# best technique to... (sax, xpath, transform?)

Tags: json

Take the following json:

```
in = {
 a: "a",
 b: [ 
   { x: 1 }, 
   { x: 2 }
 ]
}
```

How would I transform it to:

```
out = [ { x: 1, a: "a" },
        { x: 2, a: "a" } ]
```

This is sort of de-normalising to a table with repeated data (the application is to convert json to csv - I can run the above table through [json2csv](https://npmjs.org/package/json2csv)).

I've looked at [clarinet](https://github.com/dscape/clarinet) (sax parser, would certainly do the job), also [node-jpath](https://github.com/stsvilik/node-jpath) (xpath, should be able to do it, but I'm not sure if only as a side effect).

Could [json2json](https://github.com/joelvh/json2json) be made to work?  (At the end of the day as I'm likely to code a lot of these the quickest bloilerplateless coffeescript style coding is what I'm after :)

[EDIT] Another possible solution, [jDoc](https://github.com/bjorg/jdoc), also [JPath](http://www.s-anand.net/blog/jpath-xpath-for-javascript/), however after some rummaging around there does appear to be code already worked out... [jsoncsv](https://github.com/gradus/jsoncsvj).
[EDIT] While json2csv only renders the top level of an object, jsoncsv seems to only render the top two or so levels (I've yet to actually get this latter code to work).

Comment: From what you've posted it's not entirely clear what the rules of the transformation are.